# Using a matroid to model emotional temperament.

Tags: matroids

An idiot crank devised a model of emotional temperament using a bitmask, $XYZ$. $X$ represent the bit that means "able to handle extreme negative emotions." $Y$ represents the bit that means "able to handle neutral emotions" (e.g. boredom, interest, contentment). $Z$ represents the bit that means "able to handle extreme positive emotions." So in this model a human could have the following eight emotional temperaments.

- $000$: can't handle any emotions.
- $001$: can only handle extreme happiness (manic temperament).
- $010$: can only handle neutral emotions.
- $011$: can handle both neutral emotions and extreme happiness, but not negative emotions.
- $100$: can handle only extreme negative emotions (depressive temperament).
- $101$: can handle either extreme negative emotions or extreme positive emotions, but not neutral ones (bipolar temperament).
- $110$: can handle both extreme negative emotions and neutral emotions, but not extreme happiness.
- $111$: can handle the entire emotional spectrum.

For the transition $\{000\} \to \{100, 010, 001\}$ this model behaves like a matroid because you only need to learn one more temperament to advance to the next level. For the transition $\{100, 010, 001\} \to \{110, 101, 011
\}$ this model still behaves like a matroid because you only need to learn one more temperament to advance to the next level. But for the transition $\{100, 010, 001\} \to \{111\}$ this model does **not** behave like a matroid, because, for example, a person who is $011$ temperament would need to learn **three** temperaments ($100$, $110$, $101$) to advance to the next level. Is there a way to fix this model so that it is turned into a matroid?

Comment: What do you mean by "behaves like a matroid"? Also, who is the crank? Can we get a reference?

Comment: @AaronDall if you really insist on a reference: http://www.72archetypes.com/wiki/table_formats You should know that he reverses it. XYZ in my post corresponds to {-3, -2} {-1, 0, 1} {2, 3} while his goes {3, 2} {1, 0, -1} {-2, -3}. Mine corresponds to the number line. That's why it is the way it is: so the isomorphism to the number line is preserved.

Comment: @AaronDall my intuitive understanding of a matroid is that it's a structure on which "greedy" algorithms work. You can add bit by bit and get the optimal situation.

Comment: Let's put intuition aside and get concrete. A matroid is a pair $(E, I)$ where $E$ is a finite set (the *ground set*) and $I$ is a collection of subsets of $E$ (the *independent sets* of the matroid) such that for any weight function $w$ on $E$ the greedy algorithm selects a cardinality maximal element of $I$ that is also $w$-maximal. What is the ground set you're considering? Is it $E = \{1,2,3\}$? What are the independent sets you are considering? Is it all subsets of $E$?

Comment: @AaronDall Yes and yes.